# Get json data to html table

Tags: html, json

I have a json data from a mysql table that is queried from a php script. The json data is coming correctly like this:

```
{
"report": [{
    "Mes": "Abril",
    "Dia": "13",
    "Local": "Lisboa",

}]
}
```

I tried this code to get the data into a html table. But since i'm a noob I don't know why isn't working.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $.getJSON("http://ib.esy.es/_php/select_comissao1.php",
    function (data) {
        var tr = data.report
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            tr = $('<tr/>');
            tr.append("<td>" + data[i].Mes + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + data[i].Dia + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + data[i].Local + "</td>");
            $('.table1').append(tr);
        }
    });
    </script>

    <table class="table1">
        <tr>
            <th>Mes</th>
            <th>Dia</th>
            <th>Hora</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: What's the specific issue that isn't working? Right now it's rather difficult to figure out what you're asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're saying the JSON is coming back, and assuming the object structure in the question is correct, a couple things stand out to me:

1) I don't understand why this line `var tr = data.report` is in the code.  You're setting `tr` to your fetched data and then overwriting it with a jquery object in your loop.

2) The reason you're unable to get the data out of your JSON is that `data` is the root of your object.  The data you're trying to write to the table is in the `report` property within the top-level `data` object.  You can update your javascript to:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.report.length; i++) {
  var tr = $('<tr/>');
  $(tr).append("<td>" + data.report[i].Mes + "</td>");
  $(tr).append("<td>" + data.report[i].Dia + "</td>");
  $(tr).append("<td>" + data.report[i].Local + "</td>");
  $('.table1').append(tr);
}
```

With the previous code, you were indexing into the `data` object which is not an array.  This update makes sure the indexing is happening on the `report` property, which is an array.

**Sample**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Using the JSON format from your question
  var data = {
    "report": [{
        "Mes": "Abril",
        "Dia": "13",
        "Local": "Lisboa",

    }]
  };

  // Loop through data.report instead of data
  for (var i = 0; i < data.report.length; i++) {
    var tr = $('<tr/>');
    
    // Indexing into data.report for each td element
    $(tr).append("<td>" + data.report[i].Mes + "</td>");
    $(tr).append("<td>" + data.report[i].Dia + "</td>");
    $(tr).append("<td>" + data.report[i].Local + "</td>");
    $('.table1').append(tr);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table1">
  <tr>
    <th>Mes</th>
    <th>Dia</th>
    <th>Hora</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but no output is coming.

Comment: I've added a working sample to the answer for your reference.  I'm not doing the AJAX call, but if you're getting the data back correctly, this should work

Comment: But still no output, I guess the error is how push the data from url.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close. When sending async requests through JavaScript, you need to send the request to a path that is relative to your domain name. In this case, it should be `/_php/select_comissao1.php`. Just remove your domain name (`http://ib.esy.es`) from the request path.

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
       /**
         * Replace "http://ib.esy.es/_php/select_comissao1.php" with a relative path.
         * 
         * In this case, it should be "/_php/select_comissao1.php"
         */
        $.getJSON("/_php/select_comissao1.php",
            function (data) {
                var tr = data.report
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    tr = $('<tr/>');
                    tr.append("<td>" + data[i].Mes + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + data[i].Dia + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + data[i].Local + "</td>");
                    $('.table1').append(tr);
                }
            });
    </script>

    <table class="table1">
        <tr>
            <th>Mes</th>
            <th>Dia</th>
            <th>Hora</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

### Update

If your application is not running on `http://ib.esy.es`, you can execute a cross-domain ajax request with [JSONP](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/).

**Example**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://ib.esy.es/_php/select_comissao1.php",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "jsonp", //jsonp allows cross-domain ajax requests.
        success: function (data) {
                var tr = data.report
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    tr = $('<tr/>');
                    tr.append("<td>" + data[i].Mes + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + data[i].Dia + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + data[i].Local + "</td>");
                    $('.table1').append(tr);
                }
        }
    });
</script>

<table class="table1">
    <tr>
        <th>Mes</th>
        <th>Dia</th>
        <th>Hora</th>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but no output is coming

Comment: The code above is a complete example. It should work out of the box. If you are still running into problems, press `F12` on your keyboard to open the developer tools. Then go to the `console` tab (sometimes also called `JS Console`). Let me know if you see any errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

Finally the working code. It had to be the way I was pushing the data from php. The small/big difference was **.then**

```
$.getJSON("http://ib.esy.es/select_comissao1.php").then(function(data)
{console.log(data);

   var tr = data
    for (var i = 0; i < data.report.length; i++) {
    var tr = $('<tr/>');

    // Indexing into data.report for each td element
    $(tr).append("<td>" + data.report[i].Mes + "</td>");
    $(tr).append("<td>" + data.report[i].Dia + "</td>");
    $(tr).append("<td>" + data.report[i].Local + "</td>");
    $('.table1').append(tr);
    }

});
```